# android.support.v7.widget.CardView could not be found (Android Studio 1.1 Preview)

Tags: java, android

[image]

I'm trying to add CardView to my activity as the official sample. But it doesn't work.

If I run my project directly, it would lead to java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.CardView .

Comment: @Blackbelt , it's 21.0.3

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You should add it to your `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.+'
    ...
}
```

Comment: Note: Make sure you add this to the correct build.gradle file, for me it was the one marked "Module: app", not "Project: Projectname".

Comment: This page is nice to use when you need dependencies like this: http://gradleplease.appspot.com/

Comment: For api 23, it should be revised like 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.+' and 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.+'

Comment: Make sure to clean project (build) after this.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how to find the most up to date String?

I'm having difficulty finding the correct string for API 26.

Comment: For new people: see lower down solutions as this is deprecated now!

Answer (score 9):

> With the release of Android 9.0 (API level 28) there is a new version of the support library called AndroidX

And the support library will be discontinued...

Add the following to `buld.gradle:app`

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Writing my answer to provide:

> 1) updated version for `compileSdkVersion 27`.
>
> 2) usage of `implementation` instead of `compile` - [What's the difference between implementation and compile in Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle).
>
> 3) a complete version number to heed the `Avoid using + in version numbers; can lead to unpredictable and unrepeatable builds..,` warning shown by Android Studio.
>
> 4) a visual for location of `build.gradle (Module:app)`.
>
> 5) And because I was not able to write a comment below @Eun's answer.

You need to paste `implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'` in **build.gradle** [Module:app] located at, for example: MyFirstApplication `->` app `->` build.gradle

Paste in following dependencies clause:

```
dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   ...
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'


   implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'


   ...
}
```

To open from Android studio itself: (From left side) **1:Project** `->` Select **Android** view `->` **Gradle Scripts** `->` build.gradle **(Module: app)**

That is:
(If the image below is not shown You can find the image [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQju3.jpg)

[image]

Using Android Studio 3.1.4

**Edit**: Updated version numbers.

Answer (score 4):

It is all because of dependency and android version problems.

**Solution:**

**For** RecyclerView:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/>
```

Instead of: <android.support.v7.widget.CardView..

**For** CardView:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView/>
```

Instead of: <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView..

**Or simply search for and drag and drop, CardView, RecyclerView ..etc from palette panel.

**For** dependencies that supports AndroidX:

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

*Go To this Article for **full description:***
https://medium.com/@daryllwong/recyclerview-cardview-is-not-working-properly-dependency-problems-in-2019-e813ab48b3d4

Answer (score 2):

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this issue because of the corruption of cached cardview aar.

Gradle was picking local cached version of cardview. Also works by changing the library version but make sure you are not overriding `configurations.all`

**Solution:**

Close Android Studio,
In windows goto `C:\Users\Qamar\.gradle\caches` and search `cardview` delete your version folder, clean and rebuild.

Using: Android Studio 3.3 and `gradle:3.2.1`

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file change
**android.support.v7.widget.CardView**
to
**androidx.cardview.widget.CardView**

Answer (score 0):

Just click on sync now at right top side

Comment: In order to turn this into a helpful answer it requires [edit]ing for clearer phrasing, details, explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid mistakes during adding CardView, you can use Android Studio tools. In the main menu open "**Project structure...**", then "**Dependencies**", "**+**" and "**cardview**" in the search line.

At the moment Android Studio adds 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0' line to your build.gradle file. Then you can use "<*androidx.cardview.widget.CardView*>" in your layouts.

Maybe after a year or two the version or the package name will change.