# Cannot load up CardView (28.0.0)

Tags: android, android-studio, cardview

I'm trying to load up cardview frame but all I get is a grey box?

I believe that this maybe due to the version of CardView or buildToolsVersion that I've been using?

I'm a bit confused to what's gone wrong....

Here is a sample of the code.

```XML
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.docaok1.mentality_trial.app"
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"


}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':feature_origin')
    implementation project(':base')
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

```gradle
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
       android:layout_width="160dp"
       android:layout_height="190dp"
       android:layout_margin="10dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Edit:

Here is a picture of the problem.

[image: Grey Box]
[image: Can't find the class?]

Comment: So you get a 'grey box' but what is your problem with that? Wich result are you expecting? (Maybe add a screenshot of your actual result and the result you want to archive)

Comment: @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII just updated the post. Apparently it can't find the class?

Comment: Have you clicked on `File / Sync project with gradle files` already?

Comment: Yep. I've done that multiple times and have experimented with different versions of CardView

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.support.v7.widget.CardView could not be found (Android Studio 1.1 Preview)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302687/android-support-v7-widget-cardview-could-not-be-found-android-studio-1-1-previe)

Comment: tried that already :')

Comment: Can you remove builtToolVersion line and rebuilt