# How to import class and android.support.v7.widget.CardView in eclips NOT in Android studio

Tags: android, eclipse

I need to know to to import class and android.support.v7.widget.CardView in eclipse NOT in Android studio.

I tried to find the build.gradle in eclipse but not found there

Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

```
The following classes could not be found:
 - android.support.v7.widget.CardView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
```

please help

Comment: You could follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302687/android-support-v7-widget-cardview-could-not-be-found-android-studio-1-1-previe

Comment: this is in Android studio not in Ecplis

Comment: to use gradle in eclipse you will need to install that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912393/is-there-any-way-to-integrate-eclipse-with-gradle-in-android-project