# android.support.v7.widget.CardView could not be found Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am following this tutorial for Android app : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wW-AAXOy4u4

I added a list that may contain some items; For each item, I want it to be a Card. Created the card, imported dependencies in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup:android-times-square:1.6.5@aar'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

}
```

as suggested here:
[android.support.v7.widget.CardView could not be found (Android Studio 1.1 Preview)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302687/android-support-v7-widget-cardview-could-not-be-found-android-studio-1-1-previe)

Nevertheless, I still get the "android.support.v7.widget.CardView could not be found" error.

The error that I get:

```
 The following classes could not be found:
    - android.support.v7.widget.CardView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create 
    Class)
    Tip: Try to build the project.   Tip: Try to refresh the layout.
```

Here is my main_activity_single_item code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
android:elevation="4dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">




 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="105dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivMain"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvMain"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivMain"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivMain"
                android:text="Timetable"
                android:textSize="24sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvMain"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivMain"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:text="Description"
                android:textSize="16dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvClick"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:text="click here"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvDescription"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ivMain"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

What I already tried:
changed in
  `res->value->styles 
from     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
to     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">` 
(error)

```
   File .. Invalidate caches / restart
    Build project
```

I work on Android Studio, my API version is 22

Can you please, share your insights on this issue ?

Please let me know if you need some extra information.
Thank you very much.

Comment: You have to use androidx dependencies. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/cardview

Comment: `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`

Comment: The problem is because you have added androidx support in your project while you are using support v7. 

This is a Support v7 Card View.
`android.support.v7.widget.CardView`

Use this.
`androidx.cardview.widget.CardViewa`

Answer (score 1):

Either use

```
androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
```

or

```
com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
```

instead of

```
android.support.v7.widget.CardView
```

Comment: @Lea, did you get your answer. Let me know

Comment: Yes, Md. Asaduzzaman, I got my answer, thank you very much! I tried before the first solution you suggested: androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
but I had other errors afterwards ('not bound ...' something like that). I didn't try your second solution.What worked for me, was the answer from this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53089633/how-to-add-cardview-in-layout-xml-in-androidx; I thought I left a reply to the previous answer, but I am not finding it today !! Thank you very much for your answer, Md.Asaduzzaman, and thanks for checking if I found the solution. Best regards.